# Asset mapping from iOS to Android?

Tags: android, ios, resolution, porting, assets

I'm working on basically porting an app from iOS to Android and am curious about general strategies for bringing over the assets.

Our iOS project has essentially 3 classes of assets:
* Small = 480 x 320 (163 dpi)
* Large = 960 x 640 (326 dpi)
* Tall = 1136 x 640 (326 dpi)

I figure the small assets would apply for ldpi and mdpi Android devices and the large assets would apply to hdpi and xhdpi Android devices. I'm not sure this is granular enough, however, and wondering if we should request separate classes of assets for each density bucket (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, and xhdpi).

Anyone with experience in this regard, please provide some input!

Comment: DPI != screen resolution. Theoretically you could have a xhdpi device with a 240x320 screen resolution.

Comment: Rick Ross! Sorry, awesome name. I don't think I implied that DPI = screen resolution. In fact, I put the resolution right next to the DPI values from iOS.